# Hadoop: How to generate custom reduce output file name?

Tags: hadoop

Now, I use MultipuleOuputs. 
I would like to remove the suffix string "-00001" from reducer's output filename such as "xxxx-[r/m]-00001".

Is there any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

From [Hadoop javadoc to the write() method of MultipleOutputs](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.0.3-alpha/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/MultipleOutputs.html):

> Output path is a unique file generated for the namedOutput. For example, {namedOutput}-(m|r)-{part-number}

So you need to rename or merge these files on the HDFS.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it on job driver. When your job completes, change the file names. Also you could do it via terminal commands.